# Ошибка "Trying to sink unknown event type contextmenu"

Tags: gwt, javascript, java

Как заставить виджет подписаться на событие `oncontextmenu`? Использую ту же конструкцию, что и с остальными событиями:

```
widget.sinkBitlessEvent(ContextMenuEvent.getType().getName());
```

Но падает исключение:

> com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (String) `@`com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.DOMImplStandard::sinkBitlessEventImpl(Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Element;Ljava/lang/String;)([JavaScript object(19993), string: 'contextmenu']): Trying to sink unknown event type contextmenu
>   at
> com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:249)
>   at
> com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>   at
> com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:570)
>   at
> com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:298)
>   at
> com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
>   at
> com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.DOMImplStandard.sinkBitlessEventImpl(DOMImplStandard.java)
>   at
> com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.DOMImplStandard.sinkBitlessEvent(DOMImplStandard.java:141)
>   at
> com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.sinkBitlessEvent(DOM.java:1251)
>   at
> com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject.sinkBitlessEvent(UIObject.java:784)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    widget.sinkEvents(Event.ONCONTEXTMENU);//com.google.gwt.user.client.Event
    widget.addHandler(new ContextMenuHandler()
    {

        @Override
        public void onContextMenu(
            ContextMenuEvent event)
        {
            //...
        }
    }, ContextMenuEvent.getType());
```